Change job handling from FIFO to LIFO
Is there an option in Azure Pipelines that allows me to run jobs from the latest run first instead of handling all jobs of all runs in a first come first served order?
I want to get from "First-in-first-out" to  "Last In First Out" for handling of the job queue.
The reason for this is I often push to main directly an having the latest results for the last commit an the main branch is more important than having the status of older commits.


The reason for this is I often push to main directly, having the latest results for the last commit on the main branch is more important than having the status of older commits.

If the status of older commits is not important and you don't need it, maybe you can consider using the batch function in triggers.

If you have many team members uploading changes often, you may want to reduce the number of runs you start. If you set batch to true, when a pipeline is running, the system waits until the run is completed, then starts another run with all changes that have not yet been built.

In this case, once the current run is complete, the next run will run directly and will include the latest updates from the main branch.
# specific branch build with batching
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main



As per Specify jobs in your pipeline:

Azure Pipelines does not support job priority for YAML pipelines

As an alternative, you can manually click on the "Run Next" button to set the job to be run as soon as possible.
